# Powershell: Remove Duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm looking to remove duplicate entries in column A rows 2 through 500 in Sheet 1 and I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. I've seen a few examples using Select-Unique when I import the file but that doesn't fit my criteria of just Rows A2 through A500.

One option I've tried:

```
$a = worksheet.Range("A2:A500).
$range.RemoveDuplicates(1, [System.Type]::Missing, [System.Type]::Missing)
```

Admittedly, this was a suggestion from chatgpt since I couldn't find much information online and to no one's surprise, the code didn't work. In theory, it makes sense but I'm unsure what the "1" is referencing under the RemoveDuplicates function.

```
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("path")
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
(remove duplicate code here I believe)
$range = $worksheet.Range("H2:H" + $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
$range.Formula = '=QUOTIENT(G2,60) & ":" & IF(LEN(MOD(G2,60))=1,"0","") & MOD(G2,60)'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if any further info is needed.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.removeduplicates?view=excel-pia. First of all, `RemoveDuplicates` only has two parameters.

Comment: Why do you define the range in variable `$a` and next use an undefined variable  `$range` for removing duplicates? Rhe first parameter can be a singlenumeric value or an array of column indices. For the second parameter see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlyesnoguess)